# On Finding the Maximum Depth of an Arbitrarily Nested List

Tags: python, recursion

I'm currently working with a recursive function in Python, and I've run into a wall. As titled, the problem is to return the maximum depth of an arbitrarily nested list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def depthCount(lst):
    'takes an arbitrarily nested list as a parameter and returns the maximum depth to which the list has nested sub-lists.'

    var = 0

    if len(lst) > 0:

        if type(lst[0]) == list:
            var += 1
            depthCount(lst[1:])

        else:
            depthCount(lst[1:])

    else:
        return var
```

I feel that the problem is with my recursive calls (this may be obvious). It will indeed return var when the list has reached the end, but when I have a nonempty list, things go awry. Nothing is returned at all.

Am I slicing wrong? Should I be doing something before the slice in the recursive call?

The problem may also be with my base case.

Comment: Why would something be returned when there's no `return var` anywhere in the `if len(lst) > 0:` block?

Comment: Even if you want to type-switch on `list` so you don't recurse into strings, tuples, dicts, etc., do you really want to also prevent recursing into subclasses of `list`? If not, use `isinstance(lst[0], list)`.

Comment: Can you please be more specific how your "nested lists" look like? Do they contain anything other than lists, or is it literally only stuff like `[[[], []], [], [[]]]`?

Answer (score 11):

**If they are just nested lists**, e.g., `[[[], []], [], [[]]]`, here's a nice solution:

```
def depthCount(lst):
    return 1 + max(map(depthCount, lst), default=0)
```

Here's a slight variation you could use if you don't use Python 3.4, where the `default` argument was introduced:

```
def depthCount(lst):
    return len(lst) and 1 + max(map(depthCount, lst))
```

They also differ by how they count. The first considers the empty list to be depth 1, the second to be depth 0. The first one is easy to adapt, though, just make the default -1.

---

**If they're not just nested lists**, e.g., `[[[1], 'a', [-5.5]], [(6,3)], [['hi']]])`, here are adaptions to that:

```
def depthCount(x):
    return 1 + max(map(depthCount, x)) if x and isinstance(x, list) else 0

def depthCount(x):
    return int(isinstance(x, list)) and len(x) and 1 + max(map(depthCount, x))
```

Make sure you understand how the latter one works. If you don't know it yet, it'll teach you how `and` works in Python :-)

---

Taking the **"purely recursive"** challenge:

```
def depthCount(x, depth=0):
    if not x or not isinstance(x, list):
        return depth
    return max(depthCount(x[0], depth+1),
               depthCount(x[1:], depth))
```

Granted, the extra argument is slightly ugly, but I think it's ok.

Comment: Yeah, that works too. Basically, instead of passing down a flag, you've just changed it to push-down instead of push-up recursion, and merged the pushed-down depth into the flag. Which is a good idea; I usually don't think of push-down unless I'm trying to write tail-recursive code (which this obviously isn't), but there's no reason not to do it here.

Answer (score 2):

> It will indeed return var when the list has reached the end, but when I have a nonempty list, things go awry. Nothing is returned at all.

That's because you have no `return` statement, except in the `else` base case for an empty list. And if you fall off the end of the function without hitting a `return`, that means the function returns `None`.

But you have another problem on top of that. You're starting `var = 0`, then possibly doing `var += 1`… but you're not passing that down into the recursive calls, or using any result from the recursive calls. So the recursive calls have no useful effect at all.

What you probably meant is something like this:

```
def depthCount(lst):
    'takes an arbitrarily nested list as a parameter and returns the maximum depth to which the list has nested sub-lists.'

    if len(lst) > 0:

        if type(lst[0]) == list:
            return 1 + depthCount(lst[1:])
        else:
            return depthCount(lst[1:])

    else:
        return 0
```

But this still isn't actually right. The depth count of a list is 1 more than the depth count of its deepest element. Just checking its *second* element won't do you any good; you need to check *all* of them. So, what you really want is something like this:

```
def depthCount(lst):
    'takes an arbitrarily nested list as a parameter and returns the maximum depth to which the list has nested sub-lists.'
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        return 1 + max(depthCount(x) for x in lst)
    else:
        return 0
```

---

If you want to replace that iterative `for x in lst` with a *second* layer of recursion, of course you can, but I can't see any good reason to do so; it just makes the code more complicated for no reason. For example:

```
def max_child_count(lst):
    if lst:
        return max(depth_count(lst[0]), max_child_count(lst[1:]))
    else:
        return 0

def depth_count(lst):
    if isinstance(lst, list):
        return 1 + max_child_count(lst)
    else:
        return 0
```

---

This *may* still not be right. It definitely does the right thing for, e.g., `[1, [2,3], [4, [5]]]`. But what should it do for, say, `[]`? I can't tell from your question. If it should return `0` or `1`, you'll obviously need to change the `if` appropriately. If that's illegal input, then it's already doing the right thing. (And that *should* also answer the question of what it should do for, e.g., `[[[], []], [], [[]]]`, but make sure you think through that case as well.)

Comment: Your first `depthCount()` fails on `[]`. `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: @sobolevn: I'm not sure; you'd have to ask the person who wrote the assignment. If it's a bug, it's easy to fix, of course. If the right answer should be `0`, just change the condition to `if isinstance(lst, list) and lst:`. If it's supposed to be something different, you'd want a different change. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, essentially, the data structure that you're referring to is a [k-ary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) tree, also known as n-ary tree, with arbitrary branching. Here's the code for determining the max. depth of a n-ary tree with arbitrary branching.

```
def maxdepth(tree):
    if isleaf(tree):
        return 1
    maximum = 0
    for child in children(tree):
        depth = maxdepth(child)
        if depth > maximum:
            maximum = depth
    return maximum + 1
```

You can see the code in action with different test inputs [here](https://nihil.ceng.metu.edu.tr/opc/pcourse/9/2/).

Comment: Thanks Siddharth,

And if you had to solve this without using a loop?

Comment: Pure recursive... Let me think.

Comment: @Typhon: To make this purely recursive, you have to replace _both_ loops with recursion. The most readable way to do this is with two mutually-recursive functions, as at the end of my answer. But you probably don't actually want to do that.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @abarnert about this. If you want to do this purely recursively, you'll have to go about mutual recursion. :)

Comment: @SiddharthShukla: Well, you _could_ do it with one function by using a flag to effectively encode a 2-state state machine… but I think it would make it less readable, not more.

Comment: @abarnert (et al): I added a "purely recursive" single function to my answer (on the bottom). I think it's fairly readable.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, to be honest, it was more like one hour and it was in response to his comment which at the moment stated 'Thanks Siddharth' which was later edited to include request for a purely recursive function. BTW, nice soln.

Comment: @SiddharthShukla Hmm. I'm fairly certain I refreshed the page when I wrote that and it said that the question was asked "56 mins ago" and that your answer was posted "48 mins ago". I also sometimes ask people to accept my answer or someone else's, but only because it looks like they're forgetting it. Like on the next day or so and if the question is fully answered and if there is no activity anymore and if I see that they have never accepted an answer before. Otherwise I'd find it premature and possibly preventing better answers from others.

Comment: Ah, looks like we were both wrong. I was right about the 8 minutes between question and answer, but of course what matters is the time between question and your *comment*. That adds 6-12 minutes (iirc where it was). I apologize for that mistake.