# Total max of a nested list

Tags: python

### Total/Global maximum of a nested list

**Problem:**
I'm trying to find the total (or global) maximum of a nested list. The goal is to implement a function that returns the maximum value of a nested list of arbitrary depth (number of nested elements) and size (length of the nested elements).

**Expected Behavior:**

```
In [1]: nested_max([[1, 2], [[2, 1], [3, 4]]])
Out [1]: 4
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out on this.

Comment: visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427268/on-finding-the-maximum-depth-of-an-arbitrarily-nested-list/30427698) link

Comment: where did you get stuck? read this for starters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Finding the Maximum Depth of an Arbitrarily Nested List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427268/on-finding-the-maximum-depth-of-an-arbitrarily-nested-list)

Comment: `max([max(i) for i in my_list])`

Comment: Thanks @Chris_Rands this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not here to do your homework, but will make an exception:

```
def iter_list_max(alist, _max=None):
    if _max is None:
         _max = float('-inf')
    for el in alist:
         if isinstance(el, list):
             _max = iter_list_max(el, _max)
         else:
             _max = max(el, _max)
    return _max
```

Note that your list can only contain other lists of integers, check iterables for a better solution

In [70]: myl = [[1, 2], [[2, 1], [3, 4, [[1,2], [56]]]]]

In [71]: iter_list_max(myl)
Out[71]: 56

Answer (score -1):

If you can use numpy module you can get away with a one liner:

```
globalmax = np.array(list).flatten().max
```

Comment: Did you check the answer?